# vimscript comment breaking syntax highlighting

Tags: vim

I have following code in in a file sourced by my vimrc file

```
set textwidth=80 " Column at which text will be auto-rolled to next line
set winwidth=80 " this is the desired minimum, not absolute, of any new window in vim.
set splitbelow " Open new split panes to right and bottom, which feels more natural
set splitright " Open new split panes to right and bottom, which feels more natural
set ruler "always with the ruler
set laststatus=2 "always with the status line
set cmdheight=2 " command height taller
set vb " beeps for your eyes
set showmatch " show matching brackets
set number " show line numbers
set hlsearch | highlight Search cterm=underline " hilight search results while typing, underline after enter.
set cursorline " hilight current line
set showtabline=2 "always show tabs at top
set scrolloff=3 " keep more context when scrolling off the end of a buffer
set showcmd " show commands as they are entered
set wildmenu | set wildmode=list:longest,full  " autocomplete settings
```

Alternating lines in the file are not being highlighted properly. I can fix this by adding an additional quote at the end of each comment line but I don't think this is the best way to proceed.

What can I do to fix this? see img below

[image: strange syntax]

Comment: It shouldn't. It's almost like it doesn't know it's Vimscript. First off, can you tell us what `:verbose set ft?` reports? If it is anything other than `filetype=vim`, and set from anywhere other than `...runtime/filetype.vim`, you have file type detection issues rather than syntax highlighting ones. Also, make note, you are editing something that I assume is `visual_settings.vim`, not `.vimrc`.

Comment: Put `filetype plugin indent on` in your vimrc to turn on filetype detection.

Comment: @amadan the result is: filetype=vim
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim    you are also correct. that is a file sourced from my vimrc.

Comment: @fdinoff i have that in my vimrc.. not sure why it isnt working

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, filetype detection is working as intended :/ Can you inspect your vim document and tell that this phenomenon is happening from the beginning of the file, or is there a point in the file where comments start behaving this weirdly? Is it global, or triggered by something in your document? If you make a new `foo.vim` document and just copy in two of your `set` lines, does it do the same?

Comment: Your comments are alternately highlighted as literal Strings and as code, which leads me to believe syntax highlighting actually works as intended and the issue lies somewhere in the lines 1 to 6 you are not showing to us; check for unbalanced double quotes in a String and for commands that do not recognise comments at line termination in that part of your code,

Comment: @amadan unfortunately i dont think that is the case either. the first two lines are comments. line one is highlighted correctly line two is not. so after the double quote starting line two the text appears as if it is not a comment. so i dont think it can be unbalanced quotes

Comment: @kopischke see prev comment

Comment: @Andrew well how about you post the full file somewhere (Gist or Pastebin if it is too long for the question)?

Comment: @kopischke no problem! [visual_settings.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRussellHayes/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrcfiles/visual_settings.vim)

Comment: @Andrew are those spaces in your `listchar` setting on line 11? Try escaping them (i.e. `set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:·,extends:>,precedes:<,nbsp:%` – notice the backslashes).

Comment: @kopischke actually they arent spaces. i forget what code i had to type in to get it but it renders as spaces. anyway i deleted the entire line to see if it was the culprit and its not. its worth noting that he highlighting is incorrect starting at the first lines of the document

Comment: @Andrew I finally got around to loading your Gist into my Vim, and syntax highlighting is just fine; in fact , flawless, starting from line 1. I’d suggest you try two things: a.) overwrite your original file with the raw Gist contents (in case some invisible control character has messed up things and round tripping though GitHub helps); b.) check your `after/syntax/` dir and your installed plugins for possible interference with standard `vim` syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Andrew specifically, check the highlight groups *vimString* and *vimLineComment* (`1verbose hi <group>`).

Comment: @kopischke i tried some of your suggestions. overwriting didnt fix it, i couldnt find the after syntax directory in any of the locations i found referenced online. the output of the verbose commands follow: `vimString      xxx links to String
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74/syntax/vim.vim` and `vimLineComment xxx links to vimComment
        Last set from /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74/syntax/vim.vim`. Any other suggestions? Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @Andrew have you checked the output of `for id in synstack(line("."), col(".")) | echo synIDattr(id, "name") | endfor` on one of the incorrectly highlighted lines?